# iterating over relatedobjects

Tags: python, python-3.x, neo4j, py2neo

i built a minimal example for a code which I want to iterate over related objects, but it throws an error

Python version: 3.6.4 - 64bit on all systems
Seems to work on Win10 systems, but error occurs on Win7 systems
Any ideas?

minimal example of problem:

```
 class solution(GraphObject):
    __primarykey__ = "name"

    name=Property()

    includes = RelatedTo("solution")

#graph got initialized as graph

#code:
var=list(solution.select(graph))#gets a list of all solutions
for x in var:#iterates over solutions
    print(x.name)
    for y in x.includes: #not working
        print("---connected to: "+y.name) #not working
```

> error: in p2neo\packages\neo4j\v1\session.py line 124
>   session=self.session_pool.pop() IndexError: pop from an empty deque

another error occurred:

> ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061]

Does this have to do with `py2neo` or my own setup of `neo4j`?

Thanks in advance
resc

Comment: Python version: 3.6.4 - 64bit on all systems
Seems to work on Win10 systems, but error occurs on Win7 systems

Any ideas?

Comment: Please, edit your question to provide more details instead of add it on the comments.

Comment: yeah, you are right, sorry :/
goota learn a bit about formatting and posting questions here, glad all u guys help me out with that =)